# 128GB SD card worked on Raspberry Pi, but shows 2MB Size everywhere else

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card

The SD card I was using for my Raspberry Pi shows up as 2MB size both on my Fedora Laptop and on my Windows PC (using the same USB SD card reader, my only one).

So you might think, the card is obviously just broken from long use... but no until I took it out of the Raspberry Pi it was working almost flawlessly.

For the Details:

- The SD card is a SanDisk Ultra 128GB.
- It was used as the only storage medium in my raspberry for at least a year without problems.
- I took it out to reimage it and it started showing up as only 2MB in size both on my Windows PC and on my Fedora Laptop.
- The only problem I had noticed with it was two directories in the fs where any access to them would fail (I am assuming this is due to a broken sector or something similar).
- While trying to debug the issue I ran `badblocks -wvf` which overwrote the 2MB that are showing up, so I can't just put it in the raspberry and boot from it. (badblocks reported 0 errors)
- My Card Reader is a Hama 00094105 reader. According to a manual I found online it supports SD XC.

##### Is the card just gone or is there something I can do to fix it?

Given that it worked just fine minutes before I am kind of assuming that it is fixable, but I honestly have no idea what to even try at this point.

#### Edit: Clarification

I didn't just open the file explorer and look at the drive size, I opened the native partition manager (both on Windows and on Fedora as stated before) and that showed a single partion 2 MB in size.

#### Edit:

Screenshot of partitioning software. The UI is in German but everything should still be recognizable.

[image]

Comment: I would *guess* that your 2mb partition is boot partition which is visible to OSs like Windows.  You will probably find the remainder of your missing space allocated to the root partition (which Windows can't read out of the box).  Try looking at the card with any non-Microsoft partition manager and please report back what it shows you for that disk.

Comment: It's the above and/or your reader is too old to support large SD cards.

Comment: Just explaining above comment: A physical drive can have many *partitions*. One partition could be formatted FAT32, another NTFS, another ext4. If you no longer want to use the device for Raspberry Pi, *remove all partitions*, i.e., make it all free space, then make one 128 GB partition and format it (FAT32 for most OS, or exFAT if the OS can read it.).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas As I already said in my Question, I looked at the partioning both on Windows and on Fedora. I also edited my question to be clear that I actually did look at the partitioning

Comment: @ChanganAuto Do you know what to check for to determine compatibility? I added details about the reader to the question, but I am not sure what to check for

Comment: Add screenshot of disk management showing the card.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen done

Comment: You need to check it with a partition editor such as gparted for instance.  You probably can `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` for instance.  You're looking at /dev/sda1 in your screenshot which is just the first partition.

Comment: Did that same SD card work on the exact same laptop & PC, with the same card reader, in the past? If not, the card reader &/or computers just can't read that size card. Or if it used to work but doesn't, maybe the card has gone bad (or some terrible software update removed support, but on both computers linux and win, is unlikely).

Comment: I am not familiar with the Mac Disk Management tool but it seems to suggest the physical device size is incorrectly detected. That then suggests a firmware issue with the card that can not be recovered from using software but could be recoverable by a specialist, example: https://youtu.be/Qo5zynp2eWc